# What's the difference between HUAWEI AppGallery Paid Promotion and Huawei Ads Publisher Services?

Tags: huawei-mobile-services, appgallery

What's the difference between HUAWEI AppGallery Paid Promotion and Huawei Ads Publisher Services? Can I pay for ads with a credit card?

Comment: For paying for ads with enterprise credit card, it is on the development roadmap. I’ll update you once I learn more about the issue.

Answer (score 1):

The Huawei AppGallery Paid Promotion Service let's you advertise your app on the Huawei AppGallery. You would need to pay for this service in advance and create a promotion in order to use it. After that the cost for a promotion depends on the downloads of new users. More information can be found [here](https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/distribution/promotion/3020901)

The Huawei Ads Publisher Service on the other hand let's you create ads to use on your app and monetize it. You would have to integrate the [Ads Kit](https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/development/HMSCore-Guides/publisher-service-introduction-0000001050064960) to use the service.